# A abnormally working java loop,

Tags: java, loops

This is a brute force attempt to solve the problem, but it is not giving the right answer.  The program runs, but its not producing desired output. I believe the logic and program is correct.

This is [problem of a famous site](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=14) (don't want to a spoiler)

It asks for the number that produces the longest Collatz chain under one million.

```
class Euler
{

public static void main (String args[])
{
    long len,longLength=0;
    for(long i =3;i<=1000000;i++)
    {
        len = Euler14.numFucs(i);
        System.out.println("Ans"+len+"\t"+i);
        if(len>longLength)
            longLength=len;
    }
    System.out.println(longLength);
}


public static long numFucs(long num)
{
    long count=1,$test=0;
    while(num>1)
    {
        if(num%2==0)
        {
            num=num/2;

        }
        else
        {
            num=3*num+1;

        }
        count++;


    }
    //System.out.println("\tEnd");
    return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Something is wrong" - could you be a little more precise? See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Could you post any kind of information about this project Euler? I have no idea what the problem could be since I don't know what you are looking for.

Comment: @Jon Skeet loop is not giving desire answer... loop is working.. sorry ll improve in future conversations thanks

Comment: @ mike projecteuler.net has mathematical problems I am stuck @ problem 14

Comment: I think what Jon was asking was "what result were you expecting from the loop, and how does it's actual output differ from that expectation?". "They're different" doesn't really help.

Comment: Incidentally, "brutal force" is not a normal programming term - we say "brute force". However, "brutal force" does sound pretty rad, and i will start saying it now.

Comment: @RHSeeger I got u- the problem was in expectation(I got wrong idea about what was ask) thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I feel like it'd be cheating to give you the code for the right answer, as a fellow Project Euler fan. You're outputting the length of the longest chain, not the number that obtains it. If you really want, I can show you the one line that needs to change, but, honestly, this is a simple fix, and I challenge you to do it yourself.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with future problems!

Answer (score 1):

If the program is suppose to compute the number of steps in the [Collatz Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) the implementation looks fine to me.

The sequence of numbers in described by [OEIS Sequence A008908](http://oeis.org/A008908).

Here's is your program together with some debug output.

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long len, longLength = 0;
        System.out.println(Test.numFucs(13));
        String[] correct = ("1, 1, 2, 8, 3, 6, 9, 17, 4, 20, 7, 15, 10, 10, 18,"
                         + " 18, 5, 13, 21, 21, 8, 8, 16, 16, 11, 24, 11, 112, "
                         + "19, 19, 19, 107, 6, 27, 14, 14, 22, 22, 22, 35, 9, "
                         + "110, 9, 30, 17, 17, 17, 105, 12, 25, 25, 25, 12, "
                         + "12, 113, 113, 20, 33, 20, 33, 20, 20, 108, 108, 7,"
                         + " 28, 28, 28, 15, 15, 15, 103").split(", ");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 70; i++) {
            len = Test.numFucs(i);
            System.out.printf("i = %2d, Correct %3s, Computed: %3d%n", i,
                    correct[i], len);
            if (len > longLength)
                longLength = len;
        }

        System.out.println(longLength);
    }

    public static long numFucs(long num) {
        long count = 1;
        while (num > 1) {
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                num = num / 2;

            } else {
                num = 3 * num + 1;

            }
            count++;
        }

        // System.out.println(count);
        return count;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
i =  0, Correct   1, Computed:   1
i =  1, Correct   1, Computed:   1
i =  2, Correct   2, Computed:   2
i =  3, Correct   8, Computed:   8
i =  4, Correct   3, Computed:   3
i =  5, Correct   6, Computed:   6
i =  6, Correct   9, Computed:   9
i =  7, Correct  17, Computed:  17
i =  8, Correct   4, Computed:   4
i =  9, Correct  20, Computed:  20
i = 10, Correct   7, Computed:   7
i = 11, Correct  15, Computed:  15
i = 12, Correct  10, Computed:  10
i = 13, Correct  10, Computed:  10
i = 14, Correct  18, Computed:  18
i = 15, Correct  18, Computed:  18
i = 16, Correct   5, Computed:   5
...
```

As you can see it follows the OEIS sequence.

**The error must be some where else.**

Comment: Why? What's the correct answer? The given the sample input in the exercise (13) it correctly produces 10.

Comment: @ aioobe yes it give right answer for sample, I don't know the answer, just its wrong for sure...

Comment: @aioobe let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1069/discussion-between-cooleulerproject-and-aioobe)

Comment: its asking to move to chat, still do write if you get reason for abnormal functioning... thanks...

Comment: hey got the error, it was the starting number that produces the chain that i was looking for... thanks for help